# How can I get SQL Server to use User Locale for Date format for a Query?

Tags: sql-server, database, date, casting

I have created the following simple table for this test:

```
DROP TABLE DateFieldTest
CREATE TABLE DateFieldTest
(
    DateField Date NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO DateFieldTest VALUES ('2013-07-15')
INSERT INTO DateFieldTest VALUES ('2013-07-16')
INSERT INTO DateFieldTest VALUES ('2013-07-17')

INSERT INTO DateFieldTest VALUES ('2013-07-05')
INSERT INTO DateFieldTest VALUES ('2013-07-06')
INSERT INTO DateFieldTest VALUES ('2013-07-07')

INSERT INTO DateFieldTest VALUES ('2013-06-05')
INSERT INTO DateFieldTest VALUES ('2013-06-06')
INSERT INTO DateFieldTest VALUES ('2013-06-07')

INSERT INTO DateFieldTest VALUES ('2013-05-05')
INSERT INTO DateFieldTest VALUES ('2013-05-06')
INSERT INTO DateFieldTest VALUES ('2013-05-07')

SELECT * from DateFieldTest where DateField >= '2013-07-05'
SELECT * from DateFieldTest where DateField >= '2013-07-06'
SELECT * from DateFieldTest where DateField >= '2013-07-07'

SELECT * from DateFieldTest where DateField >= '05/07/2013'
SELECT * from DateFieldTest where DateField >= '06/07/2013'
SELECT * from DateFieldTest where DateField >= '07/07/2013'

SELECT * from DateFieldTest where DateField >= '07/05/2013'
SELECT * from DateFieldTest where DateField >= '07/06/2013'
SELECT * from DateFieldTest where DateField >= '07/07/2013'

SELECT * from DateFieldTest where DateField >= '24/04/2013'
```

All the queries except the last one execute.  The problem I have is that my different users have different date formats, and some users date format is dd/mm/yyyy, not the standard US/Canada of mm/dd/yyyyy.

I know I can use the convert function to cast a date, but I am working with older queries and software that is simply using the date entered by the user.  I want to know how to instruct SQL Server 2005+ to use the user's Short Date format in their locale.

Comment: Just a thought: you could create your own function to receive the date from the client and create a new one with the server's locale, by extracting the fields you need (day, month and year).

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The client software needs changing to pass the date values in parameters instead of literal strings, then locale will not be an issue.

Comment: What @ChristianHayter said.  Formatting dates is an application responsibility.  *SQL Server* has no way to way to know a user's date preference any more than his or her age or sex.  Specific apps, like SSMS, may, and if you ask about those we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the date format using `SET DATEFORMAT XXX`

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SELECT * from DateFieldTest where DateField >= '24/04/2013'
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189491.aspx